# Looking for "start publishing" field in database

Tags: joomla-3.x, phpmyadmin

I'm looking for the "start publishing" field into the xx_content of my database. I Don't see any column named like that. I can't find where its value are store.

Any idea where I could find it? (Joomla! 3.3.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `#__content` database table, the column you're looking for is `publish_up`. This contains the timestamp value for the publish date.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: But for each article the "start publishing" values saved in frontend (or backend) doesn't correspond to the "publish_up" value... I checked for several articles.

Comment: Which timezone are you? I will try to replicate what you have

Comment: thanks looder! Universal time coordinated (the dates look like that: 2011-10-15 00:00:00)

Comment: Important : I did import these articles from an 1.5 website using a query, that might be the problem.

Comment: Ahh I see. I have updated my answer with an image showing you of the test article I have just done. The `publish_up` is the correct column name that you require. If the values do not match, then there was an issue when you imported the articles from Joomla 1.5

Comment: Have a look at the query you used to import the articles from Joomla 1.5 and see how the publish date it processed

Comment: Joomla 3 will store the datetimes always in UTC timezone. If the user has a different timezone, it will calculate the difference and show the timezone adjusted datetime. This may be something that confuses.

Comment: @Bakual you solved my problem! Thank you very much for this humble and very precious comment!